# Unable to find percentage through two divs

Tags: javascript, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var a = document.getElementById("mrp4");
   var b = document.getElementById("mrp2");
   document.getElementsByClassName("dis").innerHTML = ((b.innerHTML*100)/a.innerHTML);
}
```

I'm trying to figure out the percentage between amount of my two multiple products. I've used JavaScript to increase amount with the quantity selected now. Can I add class to my same divs or can I go with id's as id'd will be same only class is in loop?

```
<div id= "mrp4">200 </div>
<div id= "mrp2">100 </div> <div id= "mrp2">120 </div>
<div class= "dis">50 </div> 
<div class= "dis">40 </div>
```

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` provides a collection of elements (note the plural `getElements` in its name). Setting a property on the collection won't automatically update all elements in the collection. You'll need to access an index (possibly in a loop) to reach and modify a specific element.

Comment: Can you try to explain what you are hoping to accomplish better? I can't fully understand what you have posted.

Comment: You have two divs with the same id, "mrp2", that contain different values.

Comment: I am listing substitutes on my page and wanted to show how much can be an extra discount , <a href="http://www.drugvilla.com/Detail.php?detail=5601"> check this </a> you may get the better idea i don't need that three percent

Answer (score 0):

Here I've cleaned it up a little bit too.

```js
(function() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("mrp4").innerHTML, 10);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("mrp2").innerHTML, 10);
  var perc = (b * 100 / a);
  console.log(a, b)
  document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = "% " + perc;
})();
```

```html
<div id="mrp4">200</div>
<div id="mrp2">100</div>
<div id="dis"></div>
```

Comment: should it be :document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML =  perc + "%" ; to give 50% in the #dis div?

Comment: Yes. I checked the website, its more complicated than this. `document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = "SAVE " +perc+" % More per STRIP";`